# Disable the flickering/blinking of UIMenuItems in UIMenuController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

How can I get rid of the flickering/blinking of `UIMenuItems` in a `UIMenuController`? I currently have copy and paste items, but when my app displays the menu inside the  action of a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, they start blinking.

```
@objc func viewLongPressed(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    [...]

    UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Are there any implementations for this in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` events get recognized **constantly** if you keep pressing the recognizer view. Calling the `setMenuVisible(animated:)` method of `UIMenuController` repeatedly causes the blinking effect you've described.

To solve this, show the menu only if the state of the recognizer is `.began`.

```
@objc func viewLongPressed(_ recognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    [...]

    if recognizer.state == .began {
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Works now